# HTML form with Apps Script won’t update Google Sheets on iPad

Tags: forms, google-sheets

HTML forms integrated with Apps Script not updating data to a Google Sheet when used on an iPad Pro tablet with any browser. The same form functions properly on Windows laptop. Are there any compatibility problems specific to mobile devices, particularly iPads?

How to fix the problem?